# Menu appearing and disappearing, transition effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

How get the effect of the menu appearing and disappearing when I press the menu change language? As shown here: [https: //wieldy.g-axon.work/main/dashboard/crypto](https://wieldy.g-axon.work/main/dashboard/crypto)

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bagqa9

```
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select 
      options={options} 
      classNamePrefix='my-className-prefix' 
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Select uses override values you can use to override the existing css. You'll want to find the CSS value for the popover and use keyframes to get that animation.